# Best practice of retrieving the String value of an Enum on the webpage using EL

Tags: java, string, enums, el

My object:

```
public class Account(){
    private String accountName;
    private AccountType accountType; // enum 

    //I customized the getter by doing this...
    public String getAccountType(){
      return accountType.getAccountType();
    }
}
```

My AccountType Enum:

```
public enum AccountType{
    OLD("Old account"),
    NEW("New account");

    private final String accountType;
    private AccountType(String accountType){
       this.accountType = accountType;
    }
    public String getAccountType(){
       return accountType;
    }

}
```

I use `${account.accountType}` to retrieve the value of the enum constant. Is this the correct way to do it?

I tried using `AccountType.valueOf("OLD")` but it returned `OLD`.

What's the best practice for things like these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your enum class like this;

```
public enum AccountType{
    OLD {
       public String type() {
           return "Old account";
       } 
    },
    NEW {
        public String type() {
            return "New account";
        }
    };
 }
```

and your Account object like this;

```
   public class Account(){
        private String accountName;    
        private AccountType accountType; // enum 

        //You don't need this.
        //public String getAccountType(){
        //    return accountType.getAccountType();
        //  }
    }
```

Then you can access `accountType.type`